# Solve $\sqrt[x]{\frac{2}{(x+1)}} = {(x+1)}^{x+2}$.

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

Please, help me solve the following exponential equation:

$$\sqrt[x]{\frac{2}{(x+1)}} = {(x+1)}^{x+2}$$

for $x \in \Bbb{R}$

**P.S.:** Sorry for all the formatting issues, I'm new in the site.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers.
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[ask], on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) 
and on writing down equations using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=(x+1)^2$ to recast the equation

$$\sqrt[x]{\frac{2}{(x+1)}} = {(x+1)}^{x+2}$$

as

$$t\ln t=2\ln2$$

which yields $t=2$, and in turn leads to the solution $x=\sqrt2-1$.

Note that $t\ln t \le 0 $ over $(0,1]$ and $(t\ln t)’>0$ for $t>1$, a strictly increasing function to assure one unique root.

Comment: For completeness, you should show that $t=2$ is the unique solution.

Comment: @Calvin Lin - Thanks for the reminder

Comment: You need more justification than that, since we could have a solution in the domain $ 0 < t \leq 1$. You could say that $ t \ln t \leq 0$ for that domain, so it cannot equal to $2 \ln 2 >0$.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward manipulations can transform the problem into solving
$$
(x+1)^{x^2+2x+1} = 2.
$$
The left-hand side is at most $1$ or undefined for $x\le0$. For $x>0$, it's not hard to show that the derivative is always positive, so that the left-hand side is increasing there and so any solution must be unique; furthermore, the values at $x=0$ and $x=1$, namely $1$ and $16$, show that a solution must exist between those two values.

I don't know a way to algebraically solve that equation, but finding an approximate root led me to conjecture that $x=\sqrt2-1$ is the solution, which (once written down) is easy to verify.

Comment: For an algebraic guess you may write $ (x+1)^{(x+1)^2} = 2 = \sqrt{2}^2 = \sqrt{2}^{\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2}$.